# How to give border to to current displaying border

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am using Shopify envy theme. I have multiple product images. I want to give border to thumb image which image is displaying as main image. In short the current image should have border.

Here is the example image what I want :[image]

Small images are multiple different thumb image. If thumb image is displaying in main big image that thumb should have border.

**This is my jQuery:**

```
$('a.image-swap').click(function() {
    var newImage = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.featured-image-div img').attr({ src: newImage });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I guess you are using some JavaScript to display the thumb in the upper preview box?

Comment: yes I am using jquery but how to give class(active to that thumb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code try this:

```
$('a.image-swap').click(function() {
var newImage = $(this).attr('href');
$( '.featured-image-div img' ).attr({ src: newImage });
$('a.image-swap').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
return false;
```

Hope will work... :)

Answer (score 1):

Therefore you are using jQuery to exchange the image you could just add a css class "active" the the displayed thumb:

Your JavaScript:

```
$('#your-element').hover(function() {
    // Your stuff for exchanging the image
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('#your-element').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Your CSS:

```
.thumb.active {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```